# Log4cplus: Does SocketAppender has an encrypting option?

Tags: sockets, ssl, encryption, log4cplus

I would like to use the SocketAppender for sending log messages to remote server, and I wonder-

Does this SocketAppender has an encryption option and an option to send the log events through ssl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not support any kind of encryption and never will.

Comment: I assume that is true for all other appenders? like the SYSLOG appender and others?

Comment: @N.avraham There is no encryption anywhere in log4cplus.

Comment: If I may ask- What is reason for the Log4cplus to not support (now and in the future) an encryption or any security level for the appenders?

Comment: @N.avraham Mainly because it is supposed to have minimal dependencies. I guess it is possible to add SSL/TLS to, e.g., the syslog appender but it would have to be only optional. Then there is a matter of picking one SSL/TLS provider library. Etc.